# How to delete a user account from TFS so that it will no longer appear in Assigned To or User Management?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

We have a situation where TFS was taken into use when we all had 2 user accounts. We started using TFS with account A but, after a while, found out that account B was better. In the end we want to use the A accounts only for RDP sessions. We would now like to remove all the A accounts from TFS so that we don't make mistakes in assigning tasks to a person.

Deleting the old accounts from the AD is not an option, we still use those accounts for RDP sessions. What we did was migrate all the WI's from account A to account B. Thereafter I removed all permissions for the old A accounts, with in mind that TFS would clear those accounts since they are no longer in use. [The double account in the assigned-to field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYYFs.png)

Unfortunately the old accounts are still visible despite they are no longer involved in any project or group. [No rights for the (development) user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FmBh.png)

How can we remove those accounts from TFS? Maybe there is somekind of cache that needs to be cleared somewhere, or a rebuild of the warehouse?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

By Default the Assigned To field shows the list of all Valid TFS Users (this is a specific TFS Group).  So if you don't want somebody to show up in that list you have to make sure they are not in the Valid TFS Users group. If you inspect this group in the TFS Admin interface you can see which other groups are members of it.  Now it's just a matter of tracing through the many TFS security groups to make sure that those user accounts are not included anywhere that would result in them being part of TFS Valid Users.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dylan. Unfortunately the accounts to be deleted not seem to be in any of these groups. That's also confirmed by my second image, the user is not a member of any TFS group nor is it in the Local Administrators Group on Windows. Any other ideas?